# Hadoop Count Query -

Tags: hadoop, count

New to Hadoop, trying to summarize records for a project.

```
select ops, ops_desc, count (*)from scm_cso_me.dailyparameters122117
Group by ops_desc
where oh in (0);
```

I receive the following error:

> java.lang.Exception: org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException:
>   Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 23:0
>   missing EOF at 'where' near 'ops_desc'

The code has several lines -- out.

Assistance is much appreciated!!

Comment: How are you running this query? From HIVE? Also, this example query has an error- you need to group by `ops` and `ops_desc`.

Comment: I am running from the hive, thank you for the correction!  I did just catch that, brand new to this.

Comment: Your help is greatly appreciated!!  I am trying to add another where statement: where oh in (0)
and cso_active_indicator is not null

Comment: would the not null portion work, not sure if the field is blank or null, trying capture records where something is in the field.  Thanks again!!

Comment: `not null` should be supported. please post your desired output.

Comment: The not null portion worked!!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Turning my comments into an answer:

The problem is that you need to group by `ops` and `ops_desc`. You can also use `not null` to eliminate records where the field value is `null`.

```
select ops,
       ops_desc,
       count (*)
  from scm_cso_me.dailyparameters122117
group by ops, ops_desc
where oh in (0)
  and cso_active_indicator is not null;
```